# How to rsync only newer (not new) files that match a pattern

Tags: rsync

I'm trying to get rsync to copy only *.ko files that are newer than their match on a target local directory.  I'm using --update but it seems that rsync still wants to copy files that are identical to the target.  I'm using this command:

```
rsync -avmR --dry-run --update --include='*.ko' --include='*/'  --exclude='*' drivers/gpu/ /lib/modules/6.1.0-rc2+/kernel/drivers/gpu/
```

I run this command after building the Linux kernel. This build creates a bunch of .ko files in several subdirectories.  For example, here's a subset:

```
$ find drivers/gpu/ -name "*.ko"
drivers/gpu/drm/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu.ko
drivers/gpu/drm/display/drm_display_helper.ko
drivers/gpu/drm/drm_vram_helper.ko
drivers/gpu/drm/hyperv/hyperv_drm.ko
drivers/gpu/drm/i915/i915.ko
```

What I want is to copy all of the *newer* .ko files to a target path under /lib/modules/6.1.0-rc2+/kernel/drivers/.  That is, a .ko file should only be copied if it *exists* on the target *and* the local version is *newer* by creation date than the matching target file.

So for example, if /lib/modules/6.1.0-rc2+/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/i915.ko  exists and drivers/gpu/drm/i915/i915.ko is newer /lib/modules/6.1.0-rc2+/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/i915.ko, then copy drivers/gpu/drm/i915/i915.ko over /lib/modules/6.1.0-rc2+/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/i915.ko.

The problem is that when I run the above rsync command, it displays .ko files that are *not* newer than their target.  For example, here you can see that virtio-gpu.ko is already the same exact file in both directories:

```
$ ls -l drivers/gpu/drm/virtio/virtio-gpu.ko /lib/modules/6.1.0-rc2+/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/virtio/virtio-gpu.ko
-rw-r--r--  1 ttabi ttabi 4992944 Jan 17 13:36 drivers/gpu/drm/virtio/virtio-gpu.ko
-rw-r--r--. 1 ttabi ttabi 4992944 Jan 17 13:36 /lib/modules/6.1.0-rc2+/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/virtio/virtio-gpu.ko
```

However, the above rsync command displays this:

```
$ rsync -avmR --dry-run --update --include='*.ko' --include='*/'  --exclude='*' drivers/gpu/ /lib/modules/6.1.0-rc2+/kernel/drivers/gpu/
building file list ... done
drivers/
drivers/gpu/
drivers/gpu/drm/
...
drivers/gpu/drm/virtio/
drivers/gpu/drm/virtio/virtio-gpu.ko
```

This tells me that if I remove the --dry-run, rsync will *unnecessarily* copy of the file virtio-gpu.ko.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Could you please **stat** the two files (driver/……/virtio… & /lib/modules……/virtio…) rather than only produce ls output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `R` in your options to the command is for relative paths, which I think means relative to where the command is invoked from.

The first thing copied is the `drivers` directory. I think that this is being copied into `/lib/modules/6.1.0-rc2+/kernel/drivers/gpu/`.

This means that the `drivers/gpu/drm/virtio/virtio-gpu.ko` file being copied is being copied to `/lib/modules/6.1.0-rc2+/kernel/drivers/gpu/drivers/gpu/drm/virtio/virtio-gpu.ko` (note the doubled `drivers/gpu`).

I would try not having the relative paths and, if you do not want `rsync` to copy files that do not already exist in the target, use `--existing` to skip creating new files.

Comment: Thanks, -R was the problem.